# MultiIndex の idxmax の結果を元にDataFrame を横展開したい

Tags: python, pandas

今、以下のような DataFrame があるとします。

```py
import pandas as pd

mi = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[['group1', 'group2'], [1,2,3,4]],
    codes=[[0,0,1,1], [0,1,2,3]],
    names=['group', 'id']
)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [400, 300, 200, 100],
    'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40],
}, index=mi)
df
```

[image: displayed df]

これに対して、 idxmax をグループしながら実行したとします。

```py
max_idx = df.groupby(level='group').idxmax()
max_idx
```

[image: displayed max_idx]

これらのデータから、以下のような DataFrame を作りたいです。

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    ('col1', 'col1'): [400, 200],
    ('col1', 'col2'): [10, 30],
    ('col2', 'col1'): [300, 20],
    ('col2', 'col2'): [100, 40]
}, index=pd.Index(['group1', 'group2'], name='group')).rename_axis(['max_at', 'original_cols'], axis=1)
```

[image: wanted result of df referring idx by idxmax]

#### 質問

最後の DataFrame を、 `df` と `max_idx` の DataFrame から導出するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: 質問に記述されている結果なのですが、``20``と``100``が入れ替わっていませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やりたい事はこんな感じでしょうか

```
import pandas as pd

mi = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[['group1', 'group2'], [1,2,3,4]],
    codes=[[0,0,1,1], [0,1,2,3]],
    names=['group', 'id']
)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [400, 300, 200, 100],
    'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40],
}, index=mi)

max_idx = df.groupby(level='group').idxmax()

ret = max_idx.apply(lambda d:d.transform(lambda d:df.loc[d]).stack(), axis=1)
print(ret)
#       col1      col2
#       col1 col2 col1 col2
#group
#group1  400   10  300   20
#group2  200   30  100   40
```

Comment: 以下、個人的なメモとして; transform は apply でも可能であることを確認しました。つまり、 `max_idx.apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda e: df.loc[e, :]).stack(), axis=1)` でもこの回答は可能